# OneHotEncoder behavior with sparse=False and without sparse=False

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, sparse-matrix, one-hot-encoding

I was trying out scikit-learn's OneHotEncoder and noticed difference in RMSE scores with LinearRegression when I use it with `sparse=False` and without `sparse=False`. I have shared the sample code below.

Additional points:

- I am using Kaggle's house price prediction data set
- I have filled the missing values outside of the pipeline shown in the code below to keep the problem statement simple.
- `num_predictors` and `cat_predictors` in the code below are the list of numerical and categorical predictors respectively.
- I have stored the data in pandas DataFrame `df_X`

Code:

```
def impute_missing_values(data):
    # Impute numerical predictors
    # Fill with median value
    data['LotFrontage'].fillna(data['LotFrontage'].median(), inplace=True)
    data['MasVnrArea'].fillna(data['MasVnrArea'].median(), inplace=True)

    # Fill with 'YearBuilt' value
    data.loc[data['GarageYrBlt'].isna(), ['GarageYrBlt']] = data['YearBuilt']
    
    # Impute categorical predictors
    data.fillna(value={'MasVnrType': data['MasVnrType'].mode()[0],
                       'Electrical': data['Electrical'].mode()[0]}, inplace=True)

    # Fill remaining NaNs in categorical predictors with 'FNA'. These are not missing
    # values. Their encoding of 'NA' was interpreted by pandas as NaNs
    data.fillna('FNA', inplace=True)


# Build the pipeline
num_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ("std_scaler", StandardScaler())
])

cat_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ("ohe", OneHotEncoder(drop='first'))
])

full_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
    ("num_transform", num_pipeline, num_predictors),
    ("col_transform", cat_pipeline, cat_predictors)
])

df_house_prices = pd.read_csv('../train.csv')

# Create a list of numerical and categorical predictors
num_predictors = df_house_prices.select_dtypes(include=np.number).columns.to_list()
num_predictors.remove('SalePrice')
cat_predictors = df_house_prices.select_dtypes(exclude=np.number).columns.to_list()

df_X = df_house_prices.copy()
impute_missing_values(df_X)

y = df_X['SalePrice']
df_X.drop(columns='SalePrice', inplace=True)

X = full_pipeline.fit_transform(df_X)

lin_reg = LinearRegression()
```

After running the above code, I run the below code:

```
lin_reg.fit(X, y)
predictions = lin_reg.predict(X)
lin_mse = mean_squared_error(y, predictions)
lin_rmse = np.sqrt(lin_mse)
lin_rmse
```

With the above code, I get an RMSE of 20514.37056811338.

If I run the same code above by changing OneHotEncoder sparse parameter to `sparse=False`, I get an RMSE of 40792.065508041254.

I have also tried with cross-validation. The code for the same is:

```
lin_scores = cross_val_score(lin_reg, X, y, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', cv=10)
lin_rmse_scores = np.sqrt(-lin_scores)
lin_rmse_mean = lin_rmse_scores.mean()
lin_rmse_std = lin_rmse_scores.std()

print(f'RMSE Scores={np.round(lin_rmse_scores, 2)}\n')
print(f'RMSE Mean={lin_rmse_mean:.2f}, RMSE Standard Deviation={lin_rmse_std:.2f}')
```

Without `sparse=False`, I get below output:

```
RMSE Scores=[57141.01 68597.65 23825.72 41094.25 30243.85 43757.96 24356.91 22624.89
 68241.47 68128.84]

RMSE Mean=44801.26, RMSE Standard Deviation=18408.26
```

With `sparse=False`, running the same code, I get the below results:

```
RMSE Scores=[2.45008393e+14 7.21914637e+15 1.35102995e+16 6.29403427e+13
 3.98734471e+13 6.73270316e+13 6.65391033e+15 4.04879886e+14
 2.46615520e+15 3.04219952e+13]

RMSE Mean=3069996248140866.00, RMSE Standard Deviation=4370204888716502.50
```

I don't understand why the model (LinearRegression, in this case) performance is different depending on whether sparse is set to True or False.  Is this expected? Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to get RMSE value same in both the cases?

Comment: Just FYI, you can take directly the RMSE from sklearn's `mean_squared_error()` using the `squared=False` argument ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html)).

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the tip @desertnaut

Comment: @naveens actually, I can't reproduce your issue with the same dataset; I get the same results. Would you mind adding the imputation part, too?

Comment: This issue should be fixed https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/13279 , so are you using an older version of sklearn?

Comment: @StupidWolf, I am using version 1.0.1. Pretty recent version. The issue you mentioned should have been fixed in this. BTW, how do I find the version of scikit-learn where this fix was merged.

Comment: @amiola, I have edited my query and provided complete code now. Can you please check. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry. Actually, I have to withdraw what I wrote. I can (and yesterday, too, I could) reproduce it, though the difference is way smaller. At the moment, Iam not able to get through it

Comment: @naveens It seems that adding `fit_intercept=False` to the `LinearRegression` instance solves the problem, though it is still unclear for me as you're already taking care of multicollinearity issues via `drop='first'` in `OneHotEncoder` (I mean if this is somehow related to, which might not be the case)

Comment: @amiola, I tried with `fit_intercept=False`. I also get similar results like what you have got and it seems to work. If I remove `standardscaler` from the pipeline and leave `fit_intercept` with default value of `True`, then also it seems to work. This is probably because `standardscaler` is centering the data.
However, the issue with `cross_val_score` does not get addressed with either of the approaches above.